# Prestashop 1.7 custom field in admin product page - Saving issue

Tags: php, twig, backend, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I've added a custom field into Prestashop 1.7 product
I'm missing something because I can't save the value of the new field(checkbox)

What did till now:

1. I've add new field to table `ps_product`

`hide_discount_table - tinyint(1) - NOT NULL`

2. override/classes/Product.php

```
    public function __construct($id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null)
        {
            self::$definition['fields']['hide_discount_table'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isBool');
        }
```

3. src/PrestaShopBundle/Form/Admin/Product/ProductInformation.php

```
    // LINE 238
    ->add('hidden_discount_table', FormType\CheckboxType::class, [
        'label' => $this->translator->trans('Hide discount table', [], 'Admin.Global'),
        'required' => false,
    ])
```

4. src/PrestaShopBundle/Model/Product/AdminModelAdapter.php:

```
    private $translatableKeys = array(
        //...LINE 140
        'hidden_discount_table',
    );
    private $unmapKeys = array(
        //... LINE 161
        'hidden_discount_table',
    );
    private function mapStep1FromData(Product $product)
    {   
        return array(
            //... LINE 518
            'hide_discount_table' => $product->hide_discount_table== 0 ? false : true,
        );
    }
```

5. src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product/ProductPage/product.html.twig:

```
    {# PANEL ESSENTIALS #}
            {% block product_panel_essentials %}
              {% set formQuantityShortcut = form.step1.qty_0_shortcut is defined ? form.step1.qty_0_shortcut : null  %}
              {{ include('@Product/ProductPage/Panels/essentials.html.twig', {
                  'formPackItems': form.step1.inputPackItems,
                  'productId': id_product,
                  'images': form.step1.vars.value.images,
                  'formShortDescription': form.step1.description_short,
                  'formDescription': form.step1.description,
                  'formManufacturer': form.step1.id_manufacturer,
                  'formHiddenDiscount': form.step1.hide_discount_table, // NEW ENTERY
                  'formFeatures': form.step1.features,
                  'formManufacturer': form.step1.id_manufacturer,
                  'formRelatedProducts': form.step1.related_products,
                  'is_combination_active': is_combination_active,
                  'has_combinations': has_combinations,
                  'formReference': form.step6.reference,
                  'formQuantityShortcut': formQuantityShortcut,
                  'formPriceShortcut': form.step1.price_shortcut,
                  'formPriceShortcutTTC': form.step1.price_ttc_shortcut,
                  'formCategories': form.step1,
                })
              }}
            {% endblock %}
```

6. src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product/ProductPage/Panels/essentials.html.twig (in right column)

```
    <div class="form-group mb-4">
      <h2>Additional features</h2>
      {{ form_widget(formHiddenDiscount) }} 
    </div>
```

On front-end, I can print the value from DB in product.tpl

```
    {$product->hide_discount_table}
```

That works fine.

**What doesn't work:**

- Saving changes - it saves other changes but doesn't see the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Try in override/classes/Product.php

```
public function __construct($id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null)
{
    parent::$definition['fields']['hide_discount_table'] = array('type' => 
    parent::TYPE_BOOL, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isBool');
    parent::__construct($id_product, $full, $id_lang, $id_shop, $context);
}
```

And delete file /var/cache/{your_environment}/class_index.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't help still the checkbox value is not save to the db.

Answer (score -1):

You should to add your field in ps_product_lang table not ps_product

Comment: Please try to elaborate your answer with some code, examples, or related documentation. Here is [How to write good answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).